# Initialize array in Kotlin based on list size

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

I need to add LineChart(using MpAndroidChart) dynamically in `LinearLayout`.

I have declared an arrayList,named list.

```
 val list = arrayListOf<ABC>()
       ....

 for (i in list) {
   chart[] = LineChart(activity)
 }
```

**What** is the value I should put inside `[]` ? Let say the `list`'s saiz is 2, I need to have 2 chart in `LinearLayout`.

How should I initialize `LineChart`?

**Example**

`chart[i] = LineChart(activity)` ???

**LineChart**

```
public class LineChart extends BarLineChartBase<LineData> implements LineDataProvider {

    public LineChart(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();

        mRenderer = new LineChartRenderer(this, mAnimator, mViewPortHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public LineData getLineData() {
        return mData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        // releases the bitmap in the renderer to avoid oom error
        if (mRenderer != null && mRenderer instanceof LineChartRenderer) {
            ((LineChartRenderer) mRenderer).releaseBitmap();
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer

```
for (i in 0 unti list.size) {
   chart[i] = LineChart(activity)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm following correctly, you can do it in one line like this:

```
val chart = Array(list.size){ LineChart(list[it]) }
```

Or:

```
val chart = list.map{ LineChart(it) }.toTypedArray()
```

(The latter creates a temporary list, which may be slightly less efficient; but it iterates through the list instead of indexing, which could be faster if the list isn't random-access.)

Comment: There is an error in line `LineChart(it)`. Error:`Type mismatch.
Required:
Context!
Found:
ABC`

Comment: Perhaps if you posted a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE), we could write some code to fit in with it…?

Comment: I need to have 2 charts. How should I initialize the array?

Comment: any idea for this?

Comment: That's still just code fragments.  But I think the rough equivalent would be `fun initializePlayers(int playerCount) = Array(playerCount){ Player(it) }`.  (Note that both Java and Kotlin conventions start functions and variables with a lower-case letter.)  That Array constructor takes two params: a size, and a lambda to construct each array element, given its index.  So I think that does all you need.

Comment: Then you'll either have to post some code we can actually compile and run, or post the error message, or perhaps even think about it yourself!

Comment: That error clearly doesn't relate to the Java code you linked, nor the code I posted in relation to it.  I'm sorry, but you're simply not providing enough information to work from, and these comments are not supposed to turn into a discussion.  If you have a Minimum, Complete, Reproducible Example, please post that here or as a new question.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)